# Why is git reset 'HEAD@{1}' throwing an error?

Tags: git, cmd

When I do a reflog I see

```
C:\dev\myproj>git reflog
dfeb578 HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from release to master
15a6cd0 HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to 15a6cd055d1ce2f1e4592bc3dcb1370c0a330dd3
d5d97e7 HEAD@{2}: merge master: Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
b215102 HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from master to release
```

I want to reset HEAD@{1} so I do

```
git reset 'HEAD@{1}'
```

But this is returning an error:

```
C:\dev\myproj>git reset 'HEAD@{1}'
fatal: ambiguous argument ''HEAD@{1}'': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Checking my branch status, I see

```
> git branch                                           
  JIRA-826-recurse-folder-nodes                        
  JIRA-827-import-duplicate-nodes-fails                
  admin-api                                            
* master
```

This is on Windows, same result using a command shell as well as Git Bash.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be seeing a different result with bash.

The problem is that `cmd` (unlike unix shells) doesn't use `'` for quoting and passes them to git literally. You can see from the error message that git tried to find a branch/file literally called `'HEAD@{1}'` (including the quotes).

Fix:

```
git reset HEAD@{1}
```

(Or

```
git reset "HEAD@{1}"
```

if you really want to add quotes.)